# How the Keras steps_per_epoch in fit_generator works

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

In Keras documentation - **steps_per_epoch:** Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from generator before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. It should typically be equal to the number of unique samples of your dataset divided by the batch size.

I have 3000 samples. 
If i set steps_per_epoch=3000 it's work slowly. If i set steps_per_epoch=300 it's work faster and i thought that Batch works!

But then I compared how much video memory is allocated in the first and second cases. And did not notice a big difference. If I use a simple **fit()** function then the difference is large. So it's real  speed up or i just process 300 examples, instead of 3000?

What for this parameter is necessary? And how can I speed up the training? 
My generator code:

```
def samples_generator(self, path_source, path_mask):
    while 1:
        file_paths_x = self.get_files(path_source)
        file_paths_y = self.get_files(path_mask)
        for path_x, path_y in zip(file_paths_x, file_paths_y):
            x = self.load_pixels(path_x, 3, cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            y = self.load_pixels(path_y, 0, cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
            yield (x, y)
```

Answer (score 9):

The `steps_per_epoch` parameter is the number of batches of samples it will take to complete one full epoch. This is dependent on your batch size. The batch size is set where you initialize your training data. For example, if you're doing this with `ImageDataGenerator.flow()` or `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()`, the batch size is specified with the `batch_size` parameter in each of these.

You said you have 3000 samples.

- If your batch size was 100, then `steps_per_epoch` would be 30.
- If your batch size was 10, then `steps_per_epoch` would be 300.
- If your batch size was 1, then `steps_per_epoch` would be 3000.

This is because `steps_per_epoch` should be equivalent to the total number of samples divided by the batch size. The process of implementing this in Keras is available in the two videos below.

The reason why you have to set `steps_per_epoch` is that the generator is designed to run indefinitely (See the [docs](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator):

> "The generator is expected to loop over its data indefinitely."

). You implemented this by setting `while 1`.
Since `fit_generator()` is supposed to run `epochs=x` times, the method must know when the next epoch begins within this indefinitely loop (and, hence, the data has to be drawn from the beginning again).

- [Image preparation for CNN training with Keras](https://youtu.be/LhEMXbjGV_4)
- [Create and train a CNN in Keras](https://youtu.be/daovGOlMbT4)