# Extremely slow training speed with Keras when using steps_per_epoch argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've noticed tremendous training model speed degradation when I specify  `steps_per_epoch` argument in `model.fit(..)` method. When I specify `steps_per_epoch` as None (or don't use it) epoch's ETA is 2 seconds straight:

> 9120/60000 [===>..........................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.7055 - acc: 0.7535

When I add `steps_per_epoch` argument, then ETA bumps up to 5 hours and training speed becomes extremely slow:

> 5/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 5:50:00 - loss: 1.9749 - acc: 0.3437

Here is the reproducible script:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import time

print(tf.__version__)


def get_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images / 255.0

model = get_model()

# Very quick - 2 seconds
start = time.time()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1)
end = time.time()
print("{} seconds", end - start)

model = get_model()

# Very slow - 5 hours
start = time.time()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=len(train_images))
end = time.time()
print("{} seconds", end - start)
```

I've also tried with pure Keras and the problem persisted. I use `1.12.0` version of Tensorflow, python 3 and Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Why does `steps_per_epoch` argument cause such a significant speed degradation and how can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's going to be slow, but 5 hours for 5 images in mnist dataset? looks way too much.  (batch size is 1 image in case of steps_per_epoch  is 60000).

Comment: Tried to run sample code with `steps_per_epoch` (with large and small steps) in both cases its failing to allocate a memory on my gpu. But using a `batch_size` (100) its running OK.

Comment: Looks like `steps_per_epoch` switch to None, is a switching `batch_size` default value (32). Guess you can find answer in another [SO topic:How the Keras steps_per_epoch in fit_generator works ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820609)

Comment: @Butuzov I've also tried setting batch_size to 1 in the first example and it worked relatively fast - only one minute of training.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice you're using `fit` with an array of data. You're not using `fit_generator` or using any generator.

There is no point in using `steps_per_epoch` unless you are having unconventional ideas.

The default batch size in `fit` is 32, this means you're training with `60000 // 32 = 1875` steps per epoch.

If you use this number 1875, you're going to train the same number of batches as the default `None`. If you use `60000` steps, you're multiplying one epoch by 32. (By the huge difference in your speed, I would say the default batch size is also changed in this case)

---

The total number shown in the output for fitting without steps is the total number of images. Notice how the number of completed items grows in multiples of 32.

The total number shown when you use steps is the number of steps. Notice how the number of completed steps grow 1 by 1.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Looks like this is it. I've changed the second example to generator usage (with batch size=32) and it worked with the same speed as the first example. I'll try this tomorrow at my work and if everything goes well, will mark the answer.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu as expected. Thanks!